# Black Virtual Bezel

Tags: display

Context: HP 8440P Laptop (NVIDIA GT218M [NVS 3100M]) outfitted with Ubuntu 16.04.

When the laptop is screen is closed, I believe the OS is 'suspended'.  When reactivated, sometimes the windows will have black 'bezels`.  The windows are active and can be seen however I have had to reboot the machine to resolve the nuisance bezel problem.   I would speculate that this is not a new problem nor is it confined to one distro

Questions:

1. What is the correct term for what I am calling the bezel so that I perform better keyword searches?
2. If this is a known problem with a fix, is there a link to said fix?

Comment: Can you capture this in a screenshot or photo?

Comment: Are you saying each window's decorations are black, i.e. the title bars and borders are black?

Comment: @Mikel Imagine a normal and complete window that is framed in a black window.